# How do I suppress spacing between paragraphs of the same CSS class?

Tags: css, spacing, paragraph

What I'd like to do is make something like ...

```
<p class="A">Line of class A</p>
<p class="B">Line of class B</p>
<p class="B">Line of class B</p>
<p class="B">Line of class B</p>
<p class="C">Line of class C</p>
<p class="C">Line of class C</p>
<p class="D">Line of class D</p>
```

... turn out like:

```
Line of class A

Line of class B
Line of class B
Line of class B

Line of class C
Line of class C

Line of class D
```

I've messed around with margins and line-height and container divs but no combination has worked for me so far. Is this possible?

Comment: I think you should accept Temani Afif's answer. It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I your elements will always be in sequence, You can simply do this:

```css
.A ~ .A,
.B ~ .B,
.C ~ .C,
.D ~ .D{
  margin-top:-15px;
}
```

```html
<p class="A">Line of class A</p>
<p class="B">Line of class B</p>
<p class="B">Line of class B</p>
<p class="B">Line of class B</p>
<p class="C">Line of class C</p>
<p class="C">Line of class C</p>
<p class="D">Line of class D</p>
```

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer. I think the other answers miss the point. _Of course_ you can put different spacing between groups of consecutive elements of the same class if you go through and identify the groups one by one and wrap them in `<div>`s or assign an additional class to the first and last of each group on a case-by-case basis, but that's not practical if, as in my case, you're dealing with ~20k lines of preexisting HTML with thousands of instances of the classes in question. I think this is what the OP had in mind, and certainly the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a nth child selector based on a class. This is not possible with CSS3.

I recomend you this reading to understand the problem you're facing: https://medium.com/@MateMarschalko/css-select-nth-element-with-class-a313d080e2bf

But I think you should make it simple, you can wrap your `<p>` tags in a `<div>` tag and use it like this:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.a p:last-of-type,
div.b p:last-of-type,
div.c p:last-of-type,
div.d p:last-of-type{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* Or just div { margin-bottom: 15px; }*/
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <p>Line of class A</p>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <p>Line of class B</p>
  <p>Line of class B</p>
  <p>Line of class B</p>
</div>
<div class="c">
  <p>Line of class C</p>
  <p>Line of class C</p>
</div>
<div class="d">
  <p>Line of class D</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work, but I hesitate to have to add groups around every group of paragraphs - most of them are normal paragraphs that should have margins above and below. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript's getElementsByClassName() method for each class and then loop through the elements until you reach the final element of each class and then add a bottom margin to it.

An easier solution that doesn't require javascript would be to make a class that adds space after the element that it's applied to and then add that class to the final element of each class. Something like this:

```css
.add-space {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p class="A add-space">Line of class A</p>
<p class="B">Line of class B</p>
<p class="B">Line of class B</p>
<p class="B add-space">Line of class B</p>
<p class="C">Line of class C</p>
<p class="C add-space">Line of class C</p>
<p class="D add-space">Line of class D</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the elements that share the same class then add margins to the wrappers.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.add-space {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="add-space">
      <p class="A">Line of class A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="add-space">
      <p class="B">Line of class B</p>
      <p class="B">Line of class B</p>
      <p class="B">Line of class B</p>
    </div>
    <div class="add-space">
      <p class="C">Line of class C</p>
      <p class="C">Line of class C</p>
    </div>
    <div class="add-space">
      <p class="D">Line of class D</p>
    </div>
```